# What is the difference between Standard Normal distribution function and probability distribution function?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, probability-distribution

I am an absolute beginner in stats and I am interested to learn it, and now I am stuck with this "standard normal distribution function" and "probability distribution" function please tell if there is any similarity between them or they are completely different

Comment: The "standard normal" distribution function is a mere subset of all possible probability distributions.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but it's suitable for stats.stackexchange.com.